# Ngbcarousel next function is not working?

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I have a list of carousel items.In one carousel item i put persanalize more button .If i click on that button ,i want to go to the next slider.How to do it in Ngular.
My .ts file is below.

```
 updatePersonalizeMobile(value){

    this.carouselindicators.next();
  }
```

When i click on the carousel item it is calling this function.

My CAROUSEL INDICATORS HTML IS AS FOLLOWS

```
<ol id="mob-form-indicators" class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active" ></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1" ></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2" ></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3" *ngIf="showDepreciation==true"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="4" *ngIf="showCompany==true"></li>
                     <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="5" ></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="6"></li>

                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="7" [hidden]="more_personalize_mobile"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="8"  [hidden]="more_personalize_mobile"></li> 
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="9"  [hidden]="more_personalize_mobile"></li> 
                     <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="10"  [hidden]="more_personalize_mobile"></li> 

                     <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="11" *ngIf="showNatureOfProfession==true"></li>
               </ol>
```

In .ts file i called the item as viwchild like this

```
@ViewChild('carousel-indicators') public carouselindicators :NgbCarousel;
```

But giving the error .next function is not defined.What to do.please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you call `updatePersonalizeMobile(...)`? You almost certainly need to preserve scope during that call.

Comment: <div class="carousel-item" [hidden]="hide_personalize">
                        <span class="btn-link link" (click)="updatePersonalizeMobile(false)" > <i class="fa fa-plus-circle  fa-lg"></i> Personalize more </span>
                    </div>

Comment: i called it inside the carousel item

Comment: When a method is called from an event (such as click), the `this` keyword is not scoped to the class. That is why your call to `this.carouselindicators` doesn't do what you expect (and also why you don't find a `next` method there. This problem is usually solved with an arrow function `() => this.works();` or with the `call`, `apply`, or `bind` JavaScript methods. This is also a pretty common question in the TypeScript tag, which is why I'm avoiding adding an answer.

Comment: where to put arrow function

Comment: @Pranav, sorry please provide more code or plnkr, provide code dosen't make much sense.